# Db2 DB21019E backup script error

Tags: shell, db2, backup

I am trying to run a backup script to backup database Sample

```
 su -c "${DB2Home}/db2 quiesce database immediate force connections" ${InstanceName} 

    echo "[INFO:`date`]Executing the backup command: ${DB2Home}/db2 backup database ${Primary_Server_DBName} to ${BackupFolder} compress without prompting "

   su -c "${DB2Home}/db2 backup database ${Primary_Server_DBName} to ${BackupFolder} compress without prompting" ${InstanceName}
```

I executed the script as a root user not as db2inst1 user

I am getting the following error

```
    [INFO:Tue Oct 21 18:44:23 IST 2014]Executing the backup command: /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/bin/db2 backup database TIPDB to /home/db2inst1/backupFolder compress without prompting 
  DB21019E  An error occurred while accessing the directory 
    "/root".
```

Comment: A simple answer is: *do not* execute DB2 commands as `root`.

Comment: I am executing the commad using su -c db2inst1 not as root

Comment: That's not what your question says.

Comment: I am running the script as a root user iam switching to db2inst1 user internally using su -c . By the way why did you downvote ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710110/how-can-i-su-from-root-to-db2inst1-and-invoke-a-sql-script-in-one-line please refer to this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add 
. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile

before the db2 operations

Comment: Why would you run multiple `su` commands, as opposed to just putting all of the necessary commands in a shell script and executing that shell script via `su` ?

Comment: This is just an example. I have only two commands. I dont require a script for it.

Answer (score -1):

Before running the script use:

```
su - db2inst1
```

then run the script as usual:

```
db2 -stvf /yourpath/createDatabase1.sql
```